# Angular 7 response .json method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I was trying to implement the `getProblems` function to get all problems in its array. But I always got an error message showing on `res.json()` saying

> Promise is not assignable to parameters of type Problem[].

I think the function is converting the response as promise and mapping it into `Problem[]` by "res.json" and passing it into `BehaviorSubject`.

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Problem } from '../models/problem.model';
    import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


    @Injectable()
    export class DataService {

    private problemsSource = new BehaviorSubject<Problem[]>([]);

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getProblems(): Observable<Problem[]> {
        this.http.get('api/problems')
          .toPromise()
          .then((res: Response) => {
            this.problemsSource.next(res.json());
          })
          .catch(this.handleError);

        return this.problemsSource.asObservable();
      }
```

P.S. I am new to `Angular` and I was trying to recycle some codes from previous project. Since `Angular` has deprecated some APIs, the following code is not working but I couldn't figure out a new way to implement it.

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following approach if your response does not require any processing.

```
getProblems(): Observable<Problem[]> {
  this.http.get<Problem[]>('api/problems')
           .toPromise()
           .then((res: Problem[]) => {
              this.problemsSource.next(res);
           })
           .catch(this.errorHandler);
  return this.problemsSource.asObservable();
}
```

FYI: `.json()` method was required for Http class which now has been [deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularhttp). The angular HttpClient automatically casts the response into a JSON object giving you support for typed return values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. then... how should i pass this into the BehaviorSubject and return it?

Comment: @JulianW. updated answer to pass value into BehaviorSubject

Comment: @JulianW. I have udpated answer to match your code. Let me know if this works

Comment: Thanks again, it said `Problem[] does not have the property .json() `. I thought the original code was using the `Response`'s method `json()` to cast it into JSON and pass it into the `problemsSource`?

Comment: @JulianW. Oh sorry. Forgot to remove that part. You don't need to do `.json()` since its already a JSON object.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. For people who have similar problems, please refer to [Angular/http](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularhttp)

Comment: @JulianW. Cool. Could you please mark this as an answer. I'll update it with the link that you shared.